# How to create bitcoin address with python

Tags: python, bitcoin

Am creating an application where i would like to create a bitcoin address for a registered user. I want to create the address so it can be used to later receive bitcoin. How can i do this using the python programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by starting a full node on your computer and connecting to it with python-bitcoinrpc.
After the node is fully configured and rpc is up and running you can get a new address on python with AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"%(RPC_USER, RPC_PASSWORD).getnewaddress() which returns the address as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import Crypto.Random

 def generate_keys(self):
        # those keys are in binary format.
        # Crypto.Random is the function that generates the random key.
        private_key=RSA.generate(1024, Crypto.Random.new().read)
        public_key=private_key.publickey()
        # DER is a binary format for data structures described by ASN.
        # from hex we decode it to ascii characters
        return binascii.hexlify(private_key.exportKey(format="DER")).decode('ascii'), binascii.hexlify(public_key.exportKey(format="DER")).decode('ascii')
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found the bitmerchant package to be useful for this.

https://github.com/sbuss/bitmerchant

You can easily create new wallets as well as child wallets along with public and private keys. The examples on the github page are quite easy to follow.